# error c2036 : unknown size if structure

Tags: c++

I have 2 class(A & C) defined in a file `allocate.h` and class B defined in `work.h`.
I included allocate.h inside work.h file
My code looks like :

```
Class A{  
}  

Class C
{  
public:  
    struct xyz{  
        A ob;  
    };  
}  

include"allocate.h"   
Class C;   
Class B{  
  void test(){  
      xyz obj; // `Error : error c2036 : xyz unknown size`  
  }  
}
```

Can someone tell me how can i communicate the size of xyz structure in function test?

Comment: I think you're missing some semicolons `;`. Did you hand copy this?

Comment: Please post the _exact_ code you are using. This code is clearly not even close to correct C++ - preprocessor includes must start with `#`, class definitions must end with `;`, and class definitions use the `class` keyword not `Class`, for starters. If you do not copy and paste _exactly_ what you are trying to compile, you may inadvertently fix the bug, or introduce new ones in the process. Also, please make it clear exactly what code is in what file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`class` in C++ (which is case-sensitive) is all lower-case and the declarations end in semicolons. Please paste *real* code into your questions!

In this instance, `xyz` is declared within the scope of `class C`, so you'll need to specify the scope when you use it.

```
class B{
    void test(){
        C::xyz obj;
    }
};
```

Comment: i was sure i am missing some basic thing. sorry for writting class in Caps, i did it deliberatley to make it more understandable.

Comment: The most understandable example you can post is an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  Here is what I would have posted: http://ideone.com/vx5Re